# Hyperlinks within a table - '<a href="">'.$row['username'].'</a>'

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have made a leaderboard table on my site, which returns the users in the MySQL database with the highest scores (score is a separate field). The fields in the leaderboard table are 'rank' 'username' and 'score'. I would like to link each username in the table to it's own profile page.

The profile pages are in the format */profile.php?user=$username*. How would I go about adding an `<a href>` within the table (which is echoed in PHP):

```
echo '<tr>
    <td>' .$a. '</td>
    <td><a href="profile.php?user=' .$row['username']. '">' .$row['username']. '</a></td>
    <td>'.$row['count'].'</td>
</tr>';
```

I've tried the above, but it doesn't seem to work. It shows the usernames, but they don't have any hyperlinks.

Comment: What does the $a variable do? I have tried it in firefox. I have tried it and it works, please tell me what the $a does?

Comment: try adding echo '<!-- ' . __FILE__ . __LINE__ . '-->'; before or after the statement. Then look if this it turns up in the output. This looks like you might be editing the wrong file. EDIT: use the magic constants for file and line I can not write the proper syntax in an comment :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$row = array(
    'username' => 'Username',
    'count' => 5
);

echo '<table><tr><td>'
    . $a . '</td><td><a href="profile.php?user='
    . $row['username'] . '">'
    . $row['username'] . '</a></td><td>'
    . $row['count'] . '</td></tr></table>';

?>
```

This works fine, I don't know what the problem is? I just do not know what `$a` does though

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct to me. I would paste the (html) source-part it outputs, to get a hint what's really going on.

The retrieval part must be good, if you're seeing your usernames, so something strange is going on.

Comment: This is the table part of the page source:
<th><font color="#00FF00">Rank</font></th>
<th><font color="#00FF00">Username</font></th>
<th><font color="#00FF00">Score</font></th>
<tr><td>1</td><td>ll</td><td>2074</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>ll</td><td>2074</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>kokok</td><td>554</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>new</td><td>237</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>taimur</td><td>134</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>lllll</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>asdd</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>8</td></tr>

Comment: That's just weird. I would add somethign in front of the <a> tags and after them, just to make sure your code is actually being executed...

Comment: And could you add some newlines to it while you're at it? :D

Answer (score 0):

Writing

```
echo '<tr> <td>'. $ a. '</ Td> <td> <a href="profile.php?user=' .$row['username'].'">'. $ Row ['username']. . '</ A> </ td> <td>' $ row ['count'] '</ td> </ tr>'.;
```

is incorrect because of:

```
</ A>
```

Correct version is:

```
echo '<tr> <td>'. $ a. '</ Td> <td> <a href="profile.php?user=' .$row['username'].'">'. $ Row ['username']. . '</ a> </ td> <td>' $ row ['count'] '</ td> </ tr>'.;
```